# Using different profiles (.kshrc_xxx) in ksh

Tags: ksh, profile

In bash you can load a different profile by using the --rcfile option, is there such an option in ksh? Or perhaps a workaround...

I know you can invoke the shell without the .kshrc profile using the +E option, however I wanting to use another .kshrc file (i.e. .kshrc_xxx) as an option instead of the default as needed.

Answer (score 2):

You can make `ksh` load another file at start by setting `ENV` in `$HOME/.profile` point to a readable file. `ksh` will run that file as a script.

Example:

```
$ echo 'ENV=$HOME/custom_kshrc' >> ~/.profile
$ echo 'export ENV' >> ~/.profile
$ . ~/.profile
$ printf 'AAA=QQQ\nexport AAA\necho Done\n' > custom_kshrc
$ ksh
Done
% env | grep AAA
AAA=QQQ
```

Comment: Not sure this is what I'm looking for... 1) wouldn't this break bash 2) This would only allow one other profile file and would be ran every time.

Comment: @CarlLindgren: You want to load another rc file instead of `.kshrc`? Just set `ENV` point to that file, example `ENV=$HOME/.kshrc_xxx`.

Comment: I want to have the option to run different environments as needed the same way I run different bashrc files and create different environments in bash.